# How to send cookies with urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, cookies, urllib

I'm attempting to connect to a website that requires you to have a specific cookie to access it. For the sake of this question, we'll call the cookie 'required_cookie' and the value 'required_value'.

This is my code:

```
import urllib
import http.cookiejar

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

opener.addheaders = [('required_cookie', 'required_value'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

req = Request('https://www.thewebsite.com/')
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
print(webpage)
```

I'm new to urllib so please answer me as a beginner

Comment: You need to add the cookie to the cookie jar, and then tell the cookie jar to add its cookies to the request.

Comment: as I said, complete beginner - how do I do this?

Comment: If you're a complete beginner, is there a reason you need to use the complicated `urllib` and `http` packages instead of `requests`? Because this entire script could be replace the the one-liner `webpage = requests.get('https://www.thewebsite.com/', cookies={'required_cookie': required_value}, headers={'User-Agent': Mozilla/5.0'}).text`.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah this works perfectly, thanks. Any chance you could put that into an answer to finish the topic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To do this with `urllib`, you need to:

- Construct a [`Cookie`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookie-objects) object. The constructor isn't documented in the docs, but if you `help(http.cookiejar.Cookie)` in the interactive interpreter, you can see that its constructor demands values for all 16 attributes. Notice that [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.Cookie) say, "It is not expected that users of http.cookiejar construct their own Cookie instances."
- Add it to the cookiejar with [`cj.set_cookie(cookie)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.CookieJar.set_cookie).
- Tell the cookiejar to add the correct headers to the request with [`cj.add_cookie_headers(req)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.CookieJar.add_cookie_header).

Assuming you've configured the policy correctly, you're set.

But this is a huge pain. As the docs for [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) say:

> **See also** The [Requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/) is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface.

And, unless you have some good reason you can't install `requests`, you really should go that way. `urllib` is tolerable for really simple cases, and it can be handy when you need to get deep under the covers—but for everything else, `requests` is much better.

With `requests`, your whole program becomes a one-liner:

```
webpage = requests.get('https://www.thewebsite.com/', cookies={'required_cookie': required_value}, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
```

… although it's probably more readable as a few lines:

```
cookies = {'required_cookie': required_value}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.thewebsite.com/', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
webpage = response.text
```

Comment: If one was stuck with just `urllib`, one could use a `MozillaCookieJar` and load a _cookies.txt_ file; this might be simpler than constructing the `Cookie` objects directly

Answer (score 9):

With the help of Kite documentation:  https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-a-cookie-to-an-http-request-using-urllib-in-python
You can add cookie this way:

```
import urllib
a_request = urllib.request.Request("http://www.kite.com/")
a_request.add_header("Cookie", "cookiename=cookievalue")
page = urllib.request.urlopen(a_request).read()
```

or in a different way:

```
from urllib.request import Request
url = "https://www.kite.com/"
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Cookie':'myCookie=lovely'})
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
```