# Web scraping after authentication using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I doing a webscraping script in Python 3.9.

I'd like to gather some informations from this website: https://www.matchendirect.fr/.
This website is in French but I don't think it's a real problem to try to help me.

The information I need is the array displayed on mouse over in the 'Pronostics des internautes' section. The HTML code start with : `<table class="table table-bordered MEDtpro">`

I have recreate cookies I've on my browser to simulate my connection following answers on this article [How to send cookies with urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682341/how-to-send-cookies-with-urllib) but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

cookies = {
    'PHPSESSID': 'a2q4evve875s1ibamiqmc93ru6',
    'c_compte_cle': '76598fbd4fe763e768dc79275c02e11f',
    'c_compte_id':'311084',
    'c_compte_pseudo':'foobar',
    'c_compte_url_image':'%2Fimage%2Fcommun%2Fmembre-med-t16.png',
    'c_coucours_promo':'3'
    }
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}


link = "https://www.matchendirect.fr/live-score/caen-toulouse.html"

response = requests.get(link, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
webpage = response.text

print("Success!") if webpage.find('<table class="table table-bordered MEDtpro">')>-1 else print("Failed!")
```

Can someone help my with this issue?

This account is a junk account for the one who would like to test on their side.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the HTML after logged in?

Comment: From what I can see, the login popup page is not using a standard login - even though it `POST`s to `https://www.matchendirect.fr/cgi/ajax/authentification_action.php?f_contexte=classique`, the form data isn't present. So maybe the Javascript on the page is modifying the input data before POSTing. You'll probably need to use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation) to interact with the page or scrape it. Anyway, since you're using `requests`, read up on [`Sessions`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). Perhaps you've not set enough cookies.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I've edit the post to remove information about account name and password. By the way, I'll delete the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content you are looking for is updated by an `AJAX` request. You can find the data by sending the request to the `AJAX` URL.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link = "https://www.matchendirect.fr/live-score/caen-toulouse.html"

response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
f_id_match = soup.find("input", {"name": "f_pronostic_id_match"})["value"]


data_response = requests.get("https://www.matchendirect.fr/cgi/ajax/liste_pronostic.php?f_id_match={}&f_id_grille=".format(f_id_match))
webpage = data_response.text


print("Success!") if webpage.find('<table class="table table-bordered MEDtpro">')>-1 else print("Failed!")
```

You need to find the `f_id_match` from the page, then send a new request to that `AJAX` url to find what you looking for.

> Do not set cookies to emulate the browser, use the `requests.Session()` to create a session like browser then try to navigate around URLs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it.

Comment: If it solves your problem, consider accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working fine.
You made a little typo in the `data_response.format`, 0 was missing between {}.